# Обновление сервиса android

Tags: android

Как свой обновить сервис не через google play, а со своего сервера?

Comment: Варианта кажется только два:  
1. Загрузить с своего сервера приложение полностью и переустановить его (чтобы пользователь нажал «установить»)  
2. Использовать DexClassLoader